# Logging queries affected by table locks in MySQL

Tags: mysql, locking, myisam

Is it possible to create a log of queries that are slowed down by MyISAM table locks? I'm trying to convince my boss that we need to convert to InnoDB to improve site performance, but need to know what sort of gains would be made.

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb

Comment: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/?s=MyISAM+InnoDB

Comment: http://tag1consulting.com/MySQL_Monitoring_and_Tuning

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, I found http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldumpslow.html

Slow query log keeps record of lock time.